# Magento 1: How to add a system configuration setting of custom module under the second module tab in admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configuration

I have two modules with same vendor name. I want to display the second module system configuration setting under first module tab in admin. Do you guys have any idea?

Here are my `system.xml` files for both modules:

*First module `system.xml`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <modulename_marketing translate="label" module="marketing">
        <label>Grz Marketo marketing Cart Integration</label>
        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
    </modulename_marketing>
</tabs> 
<sections>
    <modulename_marketing translate="label" module="marketing">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Settings</label>
        <tab>modulename_marketing</tab>
        <sort_order>140</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
       <groups>
            <marketing_settings translate="label">
                <label>marketing Cart Configurations</label>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>    
                <fields>
                  <enable translate="label">
                        <label>Enable marketing Cart Integration</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <!-- <frontend_model>modulename_Mkt_Block_Checkobjects</frontend_model> -->                 
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>10</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>10</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>10</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Send marketing Cart informations from Magento to Marketo.</comment>
                   </enable>

                </fields>

                   <fields>
                    <marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name translate="label">
                        <label>marketinged Cart custom object API name</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <depends><enable>1</enable></depends>
                    </marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name>                    
                </fields>

            </marketing_settings>
        </groups>
         <groups>
            <uzkart_standard translate="label" module="marketing">
                <label>marketing Cron Time Settings</label>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <!--maybe another fields here-->
                    <frequency translate="label">
                        <label>Frequency</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_cron_frequency</source_model>
                        <!-- Custom backend model which saves cron configuration -->
                        <backend_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_cron</backend_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </frequency>
                    <!-- Cron job time -->
                    <time translate="label">
                        <label>Start Time</label>
                        <frontend_type>time</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>201</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </time>
                </fields>
            </uzkart_standard>
        </groups>
      </modulename_marketing>
</sections>  
</config>
```

*Second module 'system.xml`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <modulename_marketing translate="label" module="marketing">
        <label>Grz Marketo marketing Cart Integration</label>
        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
    </modulename_marketing>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <modulename_marketing translate="label" module="marketing">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>marketing Cart Settings</label>
        <tab>modulename_mkt</tab>
        <sort_order>140</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
       <groups>
            <marketing_settings translate="label">
                <label>marketing Cart Configurations</label>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>    
                <fields>
                  <enable translate="label">
                        <label>Enable marketing Cart Integration</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <!-- <frontend_model>modulename_Mkt_Block_Checkobjects</frontend_model> -->                 
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>10</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>10</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>10</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Send marketing Cart informations from Magento to Marketo.</comment>
                   </enable>

                </fields>
                <fields>
                    <marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name translate="label">
                        <label>marketinged Cart custom object API name</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <depends><enable>1</enable></depends>
                    </marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name>                    
                </fields>
            </marketing_settings>
        </groups>
        <groups>
            <marketing_cron translate="label" module="marketing">
                <label>Cron Settings</label>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <!--maybe another fields here-->
                    <minutes translate="label">
                        <label>Minute</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_minute</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </minutes>
                    <hours translate="label">
                        <label>Hours</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_hour</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </hours>
                    <days translate="label">
                        <label>Days (Month)</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_day</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </days>
                    <months translate="label">
                        <label>Month</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_month</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </months>
                    <weekdays translate="label">
                        <label>Day(week)</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_weekday</source_model>
                        <!-- Custom backend model which saves cron configuration -->
                        <backend_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_weekday</backend_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </weekdays>
                </fields>
            </marketing_cron>
        </groups>
      </modulename_marketing>
</sections>  
</config>
```

Comment: Could you include the system.xml file contents of both modules here. Just to make it easy to explain

Comment: sure @nikin give me 2 min.

Comment: @nikin I have added both system.xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your second module's system.xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<sections>
    <modulename_marketing translate="label" module="marketing">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>marketing Cart Settings</label>
        <tab>modulename_marketing</tab>
        <sort_order>140</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
       <groups>
            <marketing_settings translate="label">
                <label>marketing Cart Configurations</label>
                <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>    
                <fields>
                  <enable translate="label">
                        <label>Enable marketing Cart Integration</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                        <!-- <frontend_model>modulename_Mkt_Block_Checkobjects</frontend_model> -->                 
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>10</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>10</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>10</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Send marketing Cart informations from Magento to Marketo.</comment>
                   </enable>

                </fields>
                <fields>
                    <marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name translate="label">
                        <label>marketinged Cart custom object API name</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <depends><enable>1</enable></depends>
                    </marketing_cart_custom_object_api_name>                    
                </fields>
            </marketing_settings>
        </groups>
        <groups>
            <marketing_cron translate="label" module="marketing">
                <label>Cron Settings</label>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <!--maybe another fields here-->
                    <minutes translate="label">
                        <label>Minute</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_minute</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </minutes>
                    <hours translate="label">
                        <label>Hours</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_hour</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </hours>
                    <days translate="label">
                        <label>Days (Month)</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_day</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </days>
                    <months translate="label">
                        <label>Month</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_month</source_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </months>
                    <weekdays translate="label">
                        <label>Day(week)</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_weekday</source_model>
                        <!-- Custom backend model which saves cron configuration -->
                        <backend_model>marketing/adminhtml_system_config_backend_marketing_weekday</backend_model>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <!--comment>Payment Fetch Frequency</comment-->
                    </weekdays>
                </fields>
            </marketing_cron>
        </groups>
      </modulename_marketing>
</sections>  
</config>
```

You just need to keep tab name as first tab name. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks @Ramkishan, I changed `<tab>` name of second `system.xml` file with the tab name of first `system.xml`. And it is working for me.

Comment: Great @PankajSharma. Please accept the answer it'll help others.